# Can an Application change it's own manifest file's attributes?

Tags: android

Is it possible for a custom application (.apk) downloaded from Android Store (Google) to change its own manifest attributes at run time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No (other than doing some hack, you probably don't want to get into) that would defeat the point of declaring everything upfront. But there are some things like broadcastreceivers that can also be declared dynamically, so what is it exactly you are trying to change?

Comment: If the only way by which an application can change its manifest attributes is via a hack..then it explains..I was reading about this manifest permission. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BRICK

Comment: yeah it would be awful if you could, you could go and change your own permissions and then android implodes on itself :) please mark my answer as correct if it solved your question